# 4 pictures 1 word "bot" - bad performance

Tags: java, performance, algorithm, math, logic

I think everyone of you heard about the mobile app [4 pics 1 word](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.lotum.whatsinthefoto.us&hl=en). I'm trying to write a "bot" for this game in java. Well, not actually a bot, but a program that helps to solve it.

It should basicly work like this:

```
String[] dictionary = generateArrayWithAllEnglishWordsFromTextfile();
getLengthOfWordFromUserInput();
deleteAllEntriesFromArrayWithOtherLength(); // for performance reason
getAllPossibleLettersFromUserInput();
String[] combination = getAllPossibleCombinationsOfThoseLettersWithEnteredLength();
loopThroughBothArraysAndPrintMatches();
```

I did it, and everything works fine, but if I enter 12 possible letters (what's necessary) it takes so hilariously long that it's useless.

I know java isn't the fastest language, but is it possible to make it faster than this way in java?

Comment: There are over 1 million words in the English language. An array may not be the most efficient data structure to hold this data.

Comment: what you are trying is brute force and not a smart bot which helps to solve

Answer (score 2):

```
String[] combination = getAllPossibleCombinationsOfThoseLettersWithEnteredLength();
```

Too slow.

```
loopThroughBothArraysAndPrintMatches();
```

Even slower.

Just don't do it. Keeping the style of your question, I can only say

```
result = removeAllNonMatching(dictionary, userGivenLetters)
```

In the filter, remove all words missing a required letter or all those having an illegal letter, and then do better filtering based on letter counts and whatever.

Comment: Well, that extra filter for different letters was pretty obvious. I feel dumb now... But how should I replace the two slow loops?

Comment: @Froxx organize your data in a more reasonable manner. As an example, order all of the words by length; then you can immediately look at the ones that are the same length as what the user entered.

Comment: @Froxx Drop them. Don't generate any words, just go through the dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a [Set](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) holding the English words, and then for each combination of letters, check whether the combination is a member of the Set. Checking membership in a HashSet is fast, and there are fewer short combinations than English words so this is faster than looping through all English words.

If you have 12 distinct letters and are trying to find a word with 8 letters, there are 12*11*...*5 ~ 20 million possibilities. That might be too many. Maaartinus pointed out one improvement when there are more combinations than English words: Filter the collection of English words based on statistics you calculate from the set of letters. Another approach is to use an [anagram dictionary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anagram_dictionary). When you load the English words, make a Map whose key is a function of the unordered (multi)set of letters in the word, say by sorting the letters in the word. (Let the value be the list of English words with that set of letters.) Instead of looping through all combinations of letters, you only have to go through the subsets (submultisets in case the letters are not distinct). There are only 495 subsets of size 8 of a set of size 12, so this would save a factor of 40,000 for 8 letter words from 12 distinct letters. You would request 495 values from the Map, which should be faster than iterating over all English words.